# Angular2 code not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have developed a simple code for angular2 as below.
On the page when i click the button title does not shows. Please suggest.

Below is html file code-:

```
<div>
    <button (click)="dataShow.hidden=false; searchData()">Search</button>
</div>
<div #dataShow [hidden]="true">    
    <h4>{{Title}}</h4>
</div>
```

Below is component page code-:

```
export class SearchComponent {
    Title;

    searchData() {
        this.Title="This is not working";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/uVtsjsyi7bRIqPHJRo0s?p=preview works as expected.

Comment: Not working how? Seems to be working fine https://plnkr.co/edit/94rgUrNXaKaHXTog7erw?p=preview What is the expected behavior?

Comment: I am using older version of angular2 using import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; and when i click on button no text is shown. I am using VS code.

Comment: @Gunter.....How can I run the code provided by you on Github over VS2015 and VS code

Comment: Sorry, don't know about VS2015 or VS code.